# regexp to find number between characters

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, pcre

I have a string with the following pattern:

```
......id\":\"1122575828\",\"raw_id\":1122575828,\"query\"....
```

I want to extract the number between `raw_id\":` and `','` as in `raw_id\":(the number)`,

What should be the right combination in Regexp for PCRE (PHP)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this some escaped `JSON` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regexp pattern with `preg_match` function:

```
$str = "......id\":\"1122575828\",\"raw_id\":1122575828,\"query\"....";
preg_match('/"raw_id":([^,]+?),/', $str, $matches);

$number = $matches[1];  // 1122575828
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually don't know why but on post the content altered the actually string was ...raw_id\\&quot;:1122575828,..... and I after trying for a while I got the correct expression that is /raw_id\\\\\\\\&quot;:([0-9]+),/ . Anyway your solution is correct for the altered string on my post. Thanks.